# Footer links - menu, UL or text

Tags: navigation

What is the best way to enter footer links (horizontally)? I was thinking a Menu would be best but this causes limitations around what content goes in the links (eg. cannot have images or non hyperlinked text). While looking at another drupal site I noticed that the footer links are just regular content (not even in a list) ...

What is the best way? And how would you go about deciding how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you would want to consider for "menus" not created by the Core menu system is generating any links you create with the l() function http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7

This means that at the least Drupal will add the "active" class to links that take you to the current page which can be essential for theming them properly.

Generally I'd say you should create a render array (or arrays) and get drupal go generate all the markup you need from that, but it sounds like you might be a bit too new to Drupal to be doing that.

The idea of wrapping menus in a list (ul) structure is totally optional, don't feel obligated to do it just because you've seen it elsewhere. It can help if you're doing things like drop-down menus or similar but don't worry about it magically boosting your SEO or that other people know something you don't.

You probably *do* want to wrap each item in some kind of html tag to help with theming, but that could just be a span/div.

One interesting idea to consider is a single table row as it will automatically space words out for you in a way that's difficult to do with other markup - but whether this helps or hinders is entirely dependant on the design you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of seeing the footer as a single entity you can consider it as different blocks of which the links would be a part.

So you would have a region defined as footer and add blocks to that region. One block would be the menu and could have another for the static text and may be another one for the images. and arrange the same in the order you want.

In this way the links would be managed through the menu and the rest of the things through the respective blocks.

If you are sure that the content is going to be static through out the site then it would be better to put the same in the page.tpl file.

Comment: Thank you so much for that!!! I would like to have text in between the links. I guess it is not possible to achieve this via the menus but then it wouldn't make sense to have 3 menus making up one single menu. The thing is I need a link, text, link, text, link, link. Ugggh :(